# How to get singleNode with xpath using HtmlAgility

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I need a little help.
I'm trying to do simple web scraping with HtmlAgility and C# (for the first time ever).
For the purpose of the exercise, I'm trying to scrape with XPath "Latitude and Longitude" from the "Last position" section in this website: [Ship position](https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:994899/mmsi:311000306/imo:9696773/vessel:ALFA_BALTICA)

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0UYD.png)

Here is my code so far:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string htmlCode = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:994899/mmsi:311000306/imo:9696773/vessel:ALFA_BALTICA");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
        HtmlNode node = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"vesselDetails_latestPositionSection\"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/p[5]/b/a");
```

I receive: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Sure, my question is stupid, but I'm really interested in how it can be done.

Comment: I think it might be because the website is rendered by javascript instead of pure HTML, what is the output of `htmlCode` ?

Comment: To build on what @nabais said, if the "node" is what's null look at the contents of "htmlCode" and see if that value exists you're searching for.  If it's generated through JavaScript like nabais hypothesized then you may need to load the HTML through some sort of browser object/control that has a JS engine with it.  In that scenario, you'd load the page in the browser engine control or object then use the DOM from that (or at least get what it's rendered from it to feed into the HtmlAgilityPack).